# flexisel Responsive carousel jQuery plugin listing from right

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to edit flexisel listing `<li>` to start from right to left, currently the plugin starts list elements from left to right.

When I edit `.nbs-flexisel-item` float to right all listing items disappears.

## CSS Code:

```
#flexiselDemo1, #flexiselDemo2, #flexiselDemo3 {
    display:none;
}

.nbs-flexisel-container {
    position:relative;
    max-width:100%;
}
.nbs-flexisel-ul {
    position:relative;
    width:9999px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    list-style-type:none;   
    text-align:center;  
}

.nbs-flexisel-inner {
    overflow:hidden;
    float:right;
    width:100%;  
}

.nbs-flexisel-item {
    float:right;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    cursor:pointer;
    position:relative;
    line-height:0px;
}
.nbs-flexisel-item img {
    width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    max-width:100px;
    max-height:45px;
}

/*** Navigation ***/

.nbs-flexisel-nav-left,
.nbs-flexisel-nav-right {
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px; 
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 100;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.nbs-flexisel-nav-left {
    left: 10px;
    background: url(../images/button-previous.png) no-repeat;
}

.nbs-flexisel-nav-right {
    right: 5px;
    background: url(../images/button-next.png) no-repeat;
}
```

What should I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this css code can solve the problem

```
.nbs-flexisel-inner{
    direction: ltr;
}
```